# Узнать имя класса во время исполнения программы

Tags: c++, boost

У меня есть функция (используется для записи логов), которая вызывается в разных классах. Не хочется каждый раз переписывать код в ней для каждого нового класса(они будут и добавляться и убираться со временем, ну или вообще функция будет использоваться в дальнейшем в других проектах).

Мне хотелось бы узнавать имя класса, из которого она вызывается (для задания имени файлу и прочих плюшек) не передавая лишних параметров в функцию.

Это можно реализовать? Можно и boost`ом.

Comment: это похоже на то, что Вы хотите http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1666802/is-there-a-class-macro-in-c

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Функция `typeid(object)` возвращает объект типа `type_info` с информацией о типе объекта, для которого она вызывается (собственно, о классе). У этого объекта(`type_info`) есть метод `name()`, который и возвращает имя класса.
Для использования нужно подключить `<typeinfo>`.

Так что в итоге для получения имени класса нужно использовать

`typeid(*this).name()`

Или, если функция не является методом класса, передать в `typeid` сам объект или разыменованный указатель.

Comment: Никто не гарантирует, что `name()` вернёт «человеческое» имя. Как показывает практика, в некоторых компиляторах, эти имена ничего не могут сказать человеку.

Answer (score 2):

Собственные средства c++ не позволяют ничего узнать о контектсте вызова функции.

Стек вызова можно проанализировать с помощью некоторых внешних библиотек / API операционной системы. Например: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/backtrace.3.html https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms680650%28VS.85%29.aspx . Но для применение этих средств может налагать дополнительные ограничения на собираемый код (сборка с отладочной информацией и т.д.).

Более разумно, ИМХО, передавать контекст вызова явно: это позволит использовать "штатные" средства c++: `__FILE__`, `__LINE__`, `__func__`, ....
Извлечение контекста можно замаскировать макросом:

```
  struct Context{ 
        const char* file;
        unsigned line;
        const char* function;
  };
  // Work around MSVS
  #ifndef __func__
  #define __func__ __FUNCTION__
  #endif
  #define CONTEXT() Context({ __FILE__, __LINE__, __func__})

  void foo( int a, int b, Context  c );
  #define FOO(a, b) foo( a, b, CONTEXT() )
```

Имя класса можно извлечь либо разобрав имя `__FUNCTION__`, либо из указателя this :

```
 typeid(this).name()
```

Но не хочется включать этот обращение к this в макрос, поскольку функции может быть вызвана из контекста, статической функции.

С другой стороны для целей разделения логов может быть достаточно `__FILE__`.

Comment: Только нужно имя класса, а не функции...

Comment: нестандартный `__PRETTY_FUNCTION__` содержит в себе имя класса. Работает, вроде, на всех известных компиляторах. Т.е. нужно завернуть вызов в макрос, где подставляемым аргументом будет `__PRETTY_FUNCTION__`, а внутри уже сделать разбор и вынуть нужное. Ну или бегать по стеку, что тоже нестандартизировано.

Comment: Точнее, MSVC имя класса отображает даже для `__FUNCTION__`, так что можно играться с `#ifdef/#else/#endif`